# Cannot assign value of type '() -> Void' to '(() -> Void)!'

Tags: ios, swift, casting, swift3

Since I use Swift 3 the following error appears..

> Cannot assign value of type '(LLSimpleCamera?, NSError?) -> Void' to
>   type '((LLSimpleCamera?, Error?) -> Void)!'

Does anyone know what to do?
here is my code..

```
camera.onError = { (camera: LLSimpleCamera?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Camera error: \(error)")

        if error.domain == LLSimpleCameraErrorDomain {
            if error.code == Int(LLSimpleCameraErrorCodeCameraPermission.rawValue) || error.code == Int(LLSimpleCameraErrorCodeMicrophonePermission.rawValue) {

                let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Ooops!", message: "We need permission for the camera. Please go to your settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (action) in
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
                }

                alertVC.addAction(okAction)
                alertVC.addAction(settingsAction)

                self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try replacing `camera.onError = { (camera: LLSimpleCamera?, error: NSError?) -> Void in …` with `camera.onError = { (camera: LLSimpleCamera?, error: Error?) -> Void in …`?

Comment: Yes you are right! but now Xcode says that error has no type of domain and code.. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Well, i guess you have to cast error to `NSError` inside using `as?`. Thing is that before Swift 3 there were protocol `ErrorType` and old Objective C class `NSError`, but in Swift on the way of naming simplifications both are now called `Error`(which has no domain and other properties), and all `NSError`s of ObjC are mapped to it.

Comment: Ok, i'll dub previous comment info in answer, just for sake of having question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Swift 3` maps Objective C `NSError` type to protocol `Error`(*aka* `ErrorType` in `Swift 2`).

So in closure parameters list it expects `Error` as second parameter's type instead of `NSError`.

But inside of closure you need to type case `error` parameter to `NSError` if you want to use `.domain`/`.code`/etc.